# Decay of frequencies of solution of the heat equation with a potential

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

Let $I_k = \{f \in L^2(R^n); supp(\hat{f}) \subset B(0,k) \}$.
Let $\Pi_k$ the orthogonal projection on $I_k$.
Let $a(t,x)$ a regular bounded potential.
Let $f$ the solution in $L^2$ to the Cauchy problem :
$\partial_t f - \Delta f + a f = 0, f(0,.)=f_0.$
Could we hope an estimation of this type (true for the heat equation without potential) ?
$||(1-\Pi_k)f||_2 \leq \exp(-tk^2) ||f_0||_2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "regular bounded potential" precisely? If $- \Delta f + a f = 0$ admits an $L^2$ bound state (or worse, a negative eigenvalue), then certainly you can't expect the higher frequencies to exponentially decay to zero. // If $a$ is time independent and you restrict $f_0$ to be supported only on the continuous part of the spectrum of $-\Delta + a$, then there's a chance you can read something off of the literature on the _distorted_ Fourier transforms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I mean that $a$ is $C^{\infty}$ and bounded. So, we have to suppose $a \geq 0$ in order to avoid the negative eigenvalues. Could you give me some books (or other things) on distorted Fourier transforms ?

Comment: The classic is Agmon's 1975 paper "Spectral properties of Schrödinger operators and scattering theory"; you can start from there and look up papers/books that cites it for more recent expositions.